# Names in my df's are separated into Names, Surnames and sometimes, middle names (M.) how to put them all in one column in all my df's?

Tags: r, regex, if-statement

I have a certain number of df's of which I want to change the column names, but they don't have the amount of columns because there's a Middle Name for some of the data I have. Which doesn't necessarily has to be there.

For instance

```
    df1
  X1 X2   X3   X4     X5     X6
1 A yyyy Name  M. Surname    Word1
2 A yyyy Name  M. Surname    Word1
3 A yyyy Name  M. Surname    Word1

df2
   X1 X2   X3      X4     X5
1 A yyyy Name   Surname   Word1
2 A yyyy Name   Surname   Word1
3 A yyyy Name   Surname   Word1
```

What I want for all my df's (with middle name included if it's present)

```
  Element Year         Name                 Element2
1 A      yyyy      Name (M.)  Surname          Word1
2 A      yyyy      Name (M.)  Surname          Word1
3 A      yyyy      Name (M.)  Surname          Word1
```

I have created ifelse statements based on a regex to identify middle name patterns ("[A-Z][.]+"). What's weird is that it works on regex101.com and regexr.com for the names I have in my df's but when applied to the R console as a test it returns

```
FALSE
```

regex is applied like this

```
names(df)[4] <- ifelse("[A-Z][.]+") %in% df$X4, "Middle Name", "Name")
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: How do you "apply" the regex?

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Split each row into columns by simple regex separator `\s+` and then take first two columns, last column and everything between is the full name.

Comment: Forgive me for asking this, but how?

Comment: `^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s+(\S+)$`  (see https://regex101.com/r/vGvH3F/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your condition in `ifelse` which you can check

```
"[A-Z][.]+" %in% df1$X4
[1] FALSE
```

It returns `FALSE` so you get the `else` condition.

To get a condition that returns `TRUE`:

```
library(stringr)
all(str_detect(df1$X4, "[A-Z][.]+"))
[1] TRUE
```

So use

```
names(df1)[4] <- ifelse(all(str_detect(df1$X4, "[A-Z][.]+")), "Middle Name", "Name")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid it still assigns "middle name"  as a column name to df's that don't contain any middle names.

Comment: @bolleke - my bad, I had wanted to do it with just `base`.  Brought out the heavy equipment and used `stringr`

Comment: @bolleke - happy to help.  If this answer solved your issue please accept it by clicking the checkmark.